# what to type after return in a function with a loop?

Tags: python, string, list

for the below code, it creates an array of tiers for an integer n, so for example:

```
420 should product output ["4", "42", "420"]
2017 should product output ["2", "20", "201", "2017"]
2010 should product output ["2", "20", "201", "2010"]
4020 should product output ["4", "40", "402", "4020"]
80200 should product output ["8", "80", "802", "8020", "80200"]
```

The question is, what do I type after return in the below code? Is it n? Or is it n[:I] but I know this is not right, and I know I don't need the print statement, but can someone help advise what should come after return here?

```
def create_array_of_tiers(n):
    n = str(n)
    for i in range(len(n)+1):
        print(n[:I])
    return n
```

Comment: you can use a `list` to store like `l=[]`, then instaead of prining just `append` to the list. lastly return the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a list and append the elements in the loop:

```
def create_array_of_tiers(n):
    n = str(n)
    result = []
    for i in range(1, len(n)+1):
        result.append(n[:i])
    return result

print(create_array_of_tiers(420))
```

Output:

```
['4', '42', '420']
```

You can use list comprehension to do it as:

```
n = str(420)
res = [n[:i] for i in range(1, len(n)+1)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['4', '42', '420']
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create an empty list to put the numbers in:

```
results = []
```

You then need to change line 4 so that you append the list "`results`":

```
results.append(n[:i])
```

Then just call the "`create_array_of_teirs`" method at the end, passing it the value of the number you want to list.

Your final code should look something like this:

```
def create_array_of_tiers(n):
    n = str(n)
    results = []
    for i in range(1, len(n)+1):
        results.append(n[:i])
    return results

print(create_array_of_tiers(420))
```